Cardviews not scrollable inside scrollview
In the beginning, I searched for a solution to the problem extensively but couldn't resolve it, even after trying all the solutions and answers to similar questions here.
I have a scrollview which contain cardviews but it is not scrollable .. here is the code
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cdAL1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.46">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAL1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/party_confetti"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/level1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="40sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgL1"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/description"
                    android:src="@drawable/last"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgB1"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAL1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAL1L"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/party_confetti"
                    android:text="@string/zero"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="42sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgL1"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgL1"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgL1" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgB1"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/description"
                    android:src="@drawable/best"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgL1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAL1B"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/party_confetti"
                    android:text="@string/zero"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="42sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgB1"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgB1" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/addLevel2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.46">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAL2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/party_confetti"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/level2"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="40sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgL2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/description"
                    android:src="@drawable/last"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgB2"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAL2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAL2L"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/party_confetti"
                    android:text="@string/zero"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="42sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgL2"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgL2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgL2" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgB2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/description"
                    android:src="@drawable/best"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgL2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAL2B"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/party_confetti"
                    android:text="@string/zero"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="42sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgB2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgB2" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<!-- more cardviews are here -->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>

Note: The code above is icluded in another xml file
<include
layout="@layout/###"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

EDIT: I replaced ConstraintLayout with LinearLayout and still have the same problem
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cdAL1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:cardElevation="1dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.46">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAL1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/party_confetti"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/level1"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="40sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgL1"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/description"
                        android:src="@drawable/last"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgB1"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAL1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAL1L"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/party_confetti"
                        android:text="@string/zero"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:textSize="42sp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgL1"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgL1"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgL1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgB1"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/description"
                        android:src="@drawable/best"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgL1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAL1B"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/party_confetti"
                        android:text="@string/zero"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:textSize="42sp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgB1"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgB1" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/addLevel2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:cardElevation="1dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.46">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAL2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/party_confetti"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/level2"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="40sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgL2"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/description"
                        android:src="@drawable/last"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgB2"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAL2" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAL2L"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/party_confetti"
                        android:text="@string/zero"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:textSize="42sp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgL2"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgL2"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgL2" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgB2"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/description"
                        android:src="@drawable/best"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgL2" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAL2B"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/party_confetti"
                        android:text="@string/zero"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:textSize="42sp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgB2"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgB2" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

<!-- more cardviews here -->


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView> 


The main issue with your layout is the use of a ConstraintLayout inside a ScrollView. The ConstraintLayout doesn't handle wrapping content in a way that allows it to grow vertically inside a ScrollView easily, especially with complex constraints. This can prevent the ScrollView from scrolling as expected.
Here are the steps to troubleshoot and fix the scrolling issue:
1.Ensure Vertical Layout: Ensure that your ConstraintLayout can grow vertically. Sometimes, defining app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" and app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" can restrict the height. Remove these constraints if they exist.
2.Use a LinearLayout or Nested ConstraintLayouts: A LinearLayout with vertical orientation inside the ScrollView might be more straightforward for a scrollablelist of items. You can also use nested ConstraintLayout for each card if you need complex constraints within each card.
3.Debugging the ScrollView Content: To debug, simplify the layout to see if the ScrollView starts working with basic content, then gradually add complexity. I found this solution here

Thanks for your reply .. I replaced it with LinearLayout and still have the same problem .. Tested the xml file after removing the inner linears which is horizontal and worked perfectly .. Is there an alternative way to put every two cardviews in the same line without using any alernatives like recycleview

Send your code I would check with my studio
